# What standard is SystemJS implementing?

Tags: systemjs

I heard that SystemJS implements a web standard. Does anyone know which standard it implements?

I assume when this web standard is implemented in browsers SystemJS will no longer be necessary. When is this likely to happen?

Or is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SystemJS implements roughly what the [WHATWG Loader spec](https://whatwg.github.io/loader/) proposes, however there are some [ongoing discussions](https://github.com/whatwg/loader/issues/147), some of which were implemented in SystemJS albeit not being in the WHATWG spec. Currently, there is no finalized specification of what a module loading system should look like, but most browsers are currently working on something which looks quite similar and is even somewhat compatible.

Currently, `<script type="module">` is what most browsers are working on. [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1569)/Chrome scheduled the release for version 61, the [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1240072) developers also seem to work on it, and I believe Safari already shipped it. The main issue currently appears to be that some thing were not properly specified up front, meaning that they cannot just implement what the spec says, but have to improve the spec while implementing (see the linked tickets and associated tickets for details).

Additional ongoing specification work can be found inside the [ECMAScript Harmony modules wiki page](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:modules).